# Loop through 10000 rows at a time in a dataframe of 100000

Tags: r, loops

Trying to perform sentiment analysis on a dataframe but running into some memory issues so hoping to break it into chunks. I have a dataframe thats around 100K rows and want to break up into 10K rows at a time. Any ideas on an easy way to do this programatically. Here's what I have so far:

```
#grabbing product review data
product_reviews <- dbGetQuery(conn,"select * from product_reviews";)

for (i in 1:nrow(product_reviews)) {

  # running sentiment algorithm on data, ADDING DATASET TO UPLOAD
  emo <- sentiment(product_reviews$REVIEW_TITLE)
  sql <- "select element_id,
                 avg(sentiment) as avg_sentiment,max(sentiment) as max_sentiment,
                 min(sentiment) as min_sentiment 
            from emo group by 1"
  emo_avg <- sqldf(sql)
  class_emo <- classify_emotion(product_reviews$REVIEW_TITLE, algorithm="bayes", prior=1.0)

  new <- cbind(product_reviews,
               emo_avg$avg_sentiment,
               emo_avg$max_sentiment,
               emo_avg$min_sentiment,
               emo_avg$emotion)
}
```

Basically, for the for statement, instead of looping through all rows in product_reviews, how can I loop through row 1 to 10000 first then 10001 to 20000 and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: See [mcve] on how to ask a question.

Comment: This processes the builtin BOD data frame 2 rows at a time.  The processing here is just to print that subset of rows. `for(i in seq(0, nrow(BOD)-1, 2)) print(fn$sqldf("select * from BOD limit 2 offset $i"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having memory issues, I don't know if restructuring your loop is going to help anything - it's likely that the same amount of information will need to be read, processed, and stored, regardless of how you slice it.

That being said, two ways of chunking it that immediately come to mind are by hand:

```
for(i in 1:10000) {
    stuff
}
other stuff to deal with memory issues?

for(i in 10001:20000) {
    stuff again
}
other stuff to deal with memory issues?

...
ad nauseum ad infinitum
```

or slightly more programmatically:

```
for(j in 1:ceiling(nrow(product_reviews)/10000)) {
    for(i in (10000*(j-1)+1):(min(10000*j, nrow(product_reviews)))) {
        stuff
    }
    probably some other stuff to deal with memory issues?
}
```

So ... this could win the battle but maybe not the war.  Good luck!